# Beautifulsoup not finding the tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, tags

im working on a project on beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from requests import get



url = "https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=&find_loc=New+York%2C+NY&ns=1"
clnt = get(url)
page=soup(clnt.text,"html.parser")
container = page.findAll("div",{"class":"lemon--div__373c0__1mboc container__373c0__ZB8u4 hoverable__373c0__3CcYQ margin-t3__373c0__1l90z margin-b3__373c0__q1DuY padding-t3__373c0__1gw9E padding-r3__373c0__57InZ padding-b3__373c0__342DA padding-l3__373c0__1scQ0 border--top__373c0__3gXLy border--right__373c0__1n3Iv border--bottom__373c0__3qNtD border--left__373c0__d1B7K border-color--default__373c0__3-ifU"})

container = container[1]
url2= "https://www.yelp.com"+container.a["href"]
clnt2 = get(url2)
page2 = soup(clnt2.text, 'html.parser')

info = page2.find("div",{"class":"lemon--div__373c0__1mboc island__373c0__3fs6U u-padding-t1 u-padding-r1 u-padding-b1 u-padding-l1 border--top__373c0__19Owr border--right__373c0__22AHO border--bottom__373c0__uPbXS border--left__373c0__1SjJs border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT background-color--white__373c0__GVEnp"})

contact=info.div (Example contact variable)
```

In this "info" variable i am getting the div which has all the contact details, I want to grab the Contact number form this div

And as I print this "info" variable it also shows that contact no. is present in the variable including other details but as I traverse through the div's to get the Contact No. I couldn't find it.
I have also tried to get all the child div's and even including the class of the div itself I wasn't able to get that

First url given is this  :https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=&find_loc=New+York%2C+NY&ns=1

Second url "url2" is this : https://www.yelp.com/biz/levain-bakery-new-york Which has the Contact details

Any Solutions ???

Comment: `requests` dont run java script so you wont get any dynamic content for beautifulsoup to parse, use something like selenium instead of requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the contact number with the help of the class name. But I seriously doubt if it works for any given page as the class names seem to be dynamic. But you could give it a try.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from requests import get

url = "https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=&find_loc=New+York%2C+NY&ns=1"
clnt = get(url)
page=soup(clnt.text,"html.parser")
container = page.findAll("div",{"class":"lemon--div__373c0__1mboc container__373c0__ZB8u4 hoverable__373c0__3CcYQ margin-t3__373c0__1l90z margin-b3__373c0__q1DuY padding-t3__373c0__1gw9E padding-r3__373c0__57InZ padding-b3__373c0__342DA padding-l3__373c0__1scQ0 border--top__373c0__3gXLy border--right__373c0__1n3Iv border--bottom__373c0__3qNtD border--left__373c0__d1B7K border-color--default__373c0__3-ifU"})

container = container[1]
url2= "https://www.yelp.com"+container.a["href"]
clnt2 = get(url2)
page2 = soup(clnt2.text, 'html.parser')

info = page2.find("div",{"class":"lemon--div__373c0__1mboc island__373c0__3fs6U u-padding-t1 u-padding-r1 u-padding-b1 u-padding-l1 border--top__373c0__19Owr border--right__373c0__22AHO border--bottom__373c0__uPbXS border--left__373c0__1SjJs border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT background-color--white__373c0__GVEnp"})

ContactNumber = info.find("p",{"class":"lemon--p__373c0__3Qnnj text__373c0__2pB8f text-color--normal__373c0__K_MKN text-align--left__373c0__2pnx_"})

print(ContactNumber.text)
```

Output:

```
(917) 464-3769
```

Comment: It is working for now ! but lets see ! Thanks a lot brother

Comment: Mark is answered if usefull.

Answer (score 1):

try this. I have tried for the second URL and it gives a contact number.

```
url = 'https://www.yelp.com/biz/levain-bakery-new-york'
page = requests.get(url)
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")

info = soup1.find_all("div", {
    "class": "lemon--div__373c0__1mboc island-section__373c0__3vKXy border--top__373c0__19Owr border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT"})

contact_number = info[1].find("p", attrs={
    'class': 'lemon--p__373c0__3Qnnj text__373c0__2pB8f text-color--normal__373c0__K_MKN text-align--left__373c0__2pnx_'}).text

print(contact_number)
```

approve the answer if useful. others might help it out.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from requests import get

url = "https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=&find_loc=New+York%2C+NY&ns=1"
clnt = get(url)
page=soup(clnt.text,"html.parser")
container = page.findAll("div",{"class":"lemon--div__373c0__1mboc container__373c0__ZB8u4 hoverable__373c0__3CcYQ margin-t3__373c0__1l90z margin-b3__373c0__q1DuY padding-t3__373c0__1gw9E padding-r3__373c0__57InZ padding-b3__373c0__342DA padding-l3__373c0__1scQ0 border--top__373c0__3gXLy border--right__373c0__1n3Iv border--bottom__373c0__3qNtD border--left__373c0__d1B7K border-color--default__373c0__3-ifU"})

container = container[1]
url2= "https://www.yelp.com"+container.a["href"]
clnt2 = get(url2)
page2 = soup(clnt2.text, 'html.parser')

info = page2.find("div",{"class":"lemon--div__373c0__1mboc island__373c0__3fs6U u-padding-t1 u-padding-r1 u-padding-b1 u-padding-l1 border--top__373c0__19Owr border--right__373c0__22AHO border--bottom__373c0__uPbXS border--left__373c0__1SjJs border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT background-color--white__373c0__GVEnp"})

p_tags_of_info = info.find_all("p")
print(p_tags_of_info[2].text)
```

I just extracted all the `<p>` tags from the `info` variable, and then selected the text of the third `<p>` tag.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. What gets printed for you?